# Someone sent me a pull request, what do I do?

Tags: git, github

Someone cloned my repository, fixed bugs, and sent me a pull request.

Can anyone tell me how do I pull from the users repository in github and put changes in my tree?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in the github faq:
https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

-revised due to dead link